# opengl stencil buffer not initialized with zero?

Tags: c++, opengl, glreadpixels, stencil-buffer

I work under MS WindowsXP,my video card is itel GMA4500,
my code:

```
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[width*height];
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
glReadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_STENCIL_INDEX,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
```

but when i checked the data buffer, i can see that the bytes are not all zero,
so what's the problem?

---

YES, I'm sure i have a stencil buffer, and after call glReadPixels, i checked glGetError,there's no error. i also tried memset to fill data buffer with zero, but the result didn't changed.

Comment: Does anything change if you `memset()` `data` to zeros before your `glReadPixels()` call?

Comment: So it most of the buffer is zero?  Is it a smattering on non-zero or does it have non-zero in blocks, at the start, or end?  Could you paste a (very) small hex dump?

Also, what's the width and height?

Answer (score 5):

Do you actually have a stencil buffer? If not, *glReadPixels* will raise an error (check *glGetError(…)*) and leave the target buffer's contents unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
```

since you are trying to get the contents FROM the stencil buffer?

Comment: No, `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is correct, as you are packing from GPU into client memory.